¿Como registrar varios albaranes que tienen el mismo producto?
Estoy realizando una base de datos en la cual tengo una tabla pedido y detalle de pedido, como también tengo una tabla albarán y detalle de albarán.
No hay ningún problema cuando toda la cantidad de una línea del pedido se registra en un solo albarán, pero mi duda surge cuando quiero registrar varias cantidades de la misma línea de pedido en varios albaranes.
Me explico:
Si tengo un producto en una línea de pedido con una cantidad pedida de 100 unidades, pero dicha cantidad la voy entregando en varios albaranes, un día entrego 20 unidades, otro día 25 unidades, y así hasta completar las 100 unidades del pedido.
Necesito saber cómo puedo hacer para registrar los n-albaranes con los que he entregado las 100 unidades de esa línea de pedido?, qué tablas necesitaría para luego poder realizar una consulta sobre esa línea de pedido y me diga los n-albaranes en los que se ha entregado y sus fechas de entrega.
Muchas gracias de antemano.
create table Pedido (
IdPedido int primary key identity(1,1),
NumPedido int not null,
IdCliente int references Cliente(IdCliente) not null,
FechaPedido datetime default getdate(),
Total decimal(10,2) default null
)

create table DetallePedido (
IdDetallePed int primary key identity(1,1),
IdPedido int references Pedido(IdPedido) not null,
IdProducto int references Producto(IdProducto) not null,
Cantidad int default null, --Válido para cuando se entrega toda la cantidad en un único albarán, pero no vale si se entrega en varios albaranes.
PrecioVenta decimal(10,2) default null,
IdAlbaran int references Albaran(IdAlbaran) not null --Válido cuando se entrega todo en un solo albarán pero no vale para varios albaranes.
)


Creo que esta pregunta se basa en opiniones, y podría terminar cerrada por eso. No hay respuesta concreta, solo ideas de que podrías hacer para responder. En mi caso, yo diría que una tabla que registre este tipo de información bastaría y ya.

Pero añadir una tabla y registrar la información, como? porque no todos los productos se venden en varios albaranes, sino algunos, entonces debería hacer una tabla del tipo:

create table VariosAlb(
idVariosAlb int primary key identity(1,1),
idDetallePedido int references DetallePedido(IdDetallePedido) not null,
idAlbaran int references Albaran(IdAlbaran) not null,
Cantidad int not null
)

exactamente lo que tenes que hacer...

Lo que debes hacer es añadir a tu tabla de lineas de albarán una referencia a la línea del pedido al que hace referencia esa entrega.
Puedes usar un UID para la linea de pedido, o bien usar una combinación del ID del pedido + número (o código) de la línea de pedido.
Con ese código único puedes buscar todas las lineas de albarán ligadas.
De igual forma, desde un albarán podrás indicar con facilidad a qué linea de pedido estás haciendo referencia.
Este enfoque te permite además saber en todo momento el saldo de cada linea de pedido, cuanto falta por entregar, si ha sido entregado completo el pedido e incluso si se han enviado más unidades de las solicitadas, aunque el total de unidades esté repartido entre varios albaranes. Esto es especialmente útil en aquellos mercados donde el SKU es un multiplicador de las unidades, es decir, que en cada servicio sólo es posible enviar un múltiplo concreto de unidades, lo que puede llevar a servir por encima de lo pedido.
